# Injective Hull of $k$ as $k[x_1,..., x_n]$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

Given a ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$, there is a
unique (up to isomorphism) injective $A$-module $E_A(M) $containing $M$,
with the property that every injective $A$-module containing $M$ also contains
$E_A(M)$. $E_A(M)$ is called the injective hull or injective envelope of $MS.

Example 2.32 from Richard Stanley's Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra, page 16: Let $A = k[x_1,..., x_n]$, where $k$ is a field. Regard $k$
as an $A$-module via the isomorphism $k \cong A/(x_1 A + ... + x_n A)$, Then
$E_A(k) \cong k[x_1^{-1},..., x_n^{-1}]$.

Why is $k[x_1^{-1},..., x_n^{-1}]$ the injective hull of $k$ considered as $A$-module? Is there a conceptional way (eg by using some structure results) to show it? Why is it even injective?

Comment: First, do you know the $A$ module structure on the $E_A(k)$ you have quoted from the book?

Comment: @Mohan: I think it should be the scalar multiplication for elements of $k$ and annilation by the indeterminants, ie $x_i \cdot d =0$ for $d \in E_A(M)$. But that's my guess, the book says nothing about the $A$-module structure of $E_A(k)$ , it just postulates the existence of $E_A(k)$ and then says that it should be $k[x_1^{-1},..., x_n^{-1}]$, see page 16.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: for $n=1$ we know that $k[x]$ is pid and in this case injective is equivalent to divisible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer's_criterion. But as only $k \subset A$ not annilate $k[x^{-1}]$, cleary the latter is divisible. Or did you intended me to use another argument to show that  $k[x^{-1}]$ is injective? Indeed, the argument I used not generalizes to $n>1$. So maybe there is another criterion for injectivity which you have in mind whichI should use for $n=1$ and then maybe observe that it naturaly allows to generalize the argument to $n >2$?

Comment: possibly I'm wrong, but I think that in this context we not need to assume anything about gradings, so here i'm talking just about modules

Comment: the book's definition 2.31 not says that the module should be considered as graded, so I think that the author works with 'usual' definition of injective module without grading stuff there characterized by extension property as xplained in def 2.30.

Comment: or do you trying to relate it to the other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579723/homogeneous-elements-of-matlis-dual-module-of-r-kx-y-xy where the grading of course plays a role?

Comment: the problem has been resolved. Lam's Lectures on modules and rings (Prop 3.91) contains a proof. To come back to Mohan's question about $A$ module structure of $ E_A(k)$ I was wrong. Let $I,J \in \mathbb{N}$, then the $ A$ module structure is determined by $X^I \cdot X^{ -J}= X^{I -J} $ if $ -(I-J) \in \mathbb{N}$, and zero otherwise. This solves also my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579723/homogeneous-elements-of-matlis-dual-module-of-r-kx-y-xy